# Quickest way to implement multi tenant ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant

I think I am not getting the meaning of any of this.
My purpose is to create a multi tenant ASP.NET MVC Application.

I saw a great post on how to do this [here](http://bartreyserhove.blogspot.com/2009/01/building-multi-tenant-applications-with.html)
, but Nhibernate isn't an option.

One of the things I want to understand is:
Is MVC (along with everything else) supposed to help in creating multi tenancy web apps?

I have seen several comments which are similar to my question, but they often don't appear to hit the same point I am trying to get at:

- One DB
- One Schema
- No Nhibernate

If anyone knows of a simple explanation as to how this can be done, I appreciate it.

the contents on this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) are all I know on the subject, what I wish to be able to understand is how MVC (if at all) helps in getting it done and if it makes it simpler or not.

Many thanks,

Ric

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing to answer my question here, that I can find myself is the read on [Mike Hadlow's blog](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/11/multi-tenancy-part-1-strategy.html)

Its detailed, but to the point, and I downloaded the [SutekiShop](http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/) app.

I haven't yet reached the AHA! Moment yet, but it seems close.

I believe the way he has implemented the multi tenancy was with the role id, I guess now I just have to keep reading and tweaking.

His [latest post](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/05/multi-tenanted-services-with-windsor.html) (afaik) on the subject seems to address the issue with WCF use.

Answer (score 3):

The thinks I like about MVC for multitenant applications are:

- You can choose the View according to
  your tenant

That was never easy in Webforms. Its easy to implement something in MVC like: There is a default View for every tenant, but if a tenant needs a special View, then the special View is taken. You will have to extend the Viewengine a little bit.

- You can have Business Rules according to the tenant by using IoC

By using StructureMap or others you can swap parts of your ServiceLayer

I have one DB per tenant so I will not be of help 
at the DB - part.